# How to config CKEditor-4 inline editors?

Tags: ckeditor

I have a standard installation (like samples):

```
<meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
<script src="../ckeditor.js"></script>
```

With HTML content with many `<div contenteditable="true">` blocks. I need to configure each editor by local or an external `configTypeX.js` file,

```
  <script>
   CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceCreated', function( event ) {
     var editor = event.editor, element = editor.element;
         if ( element.is( 'h1', 'h2', 'h3' ) ) {
        editor.on( 'configLoaded', function() {
            editor.config.toolbar = [
                [ 'Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic' ]
            ];  // BUG: about "Source"?? NOT AT INTERFACE!
        }); 
         } else {
            // WHERE PUT THIS ITEM?
    customConfig: 'configType2.js';
         }
   });
  </script>
```

So, my problem is

1. How to do a `customConfig` in this context?
2. Where the "best complete documentation", about config menus (`editor.config.toolbar`) without online configuration-tool, where I can understand how to put and remove menu itens with correct names?  [Here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-toolbar) nothing about how to fix the bug of 'Source' in a full installation.

---

I do,

```
git clone git://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-releases.git
cd ckeditor-releases
cp samples/inlineall.html samples/myinline.html
```

and edit `samples/myinline.html` with the code above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. For inline editors the standard `Source` button is hidden, because it is not possible to have different modes other than `wysiwyg`. Therefore for those editors new plugin was created - [sourcedialog](http://ckeditor.com/addon/sourcedialog), but it is not included in any of builds by default. You can build editor with this plugin using [online CKBuilder](http://ckeditor.com/builder) or by using one of [presets](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-presets) with `all` parameter. For example: `./build.sh full all`. Remember also to load `sourcedialog` plugin (using `config.extraPlugins = 'sourcedialog'`).
2. If you want to freely configure inline editors, then you should take a look at [inlinebycode](http://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/inlinebycode.html) sample. First you need to disable automatic editors initialization on editable elements and then call `CKEDITOR.inline()` on elements you want to become editors:

   ```
   // We need to turn off the automatic editor creation first.
   CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;

   CKEDITOR.inline( 'editable1', {
       customConfig: 'editableConfig.js'
   } );
   CKEDITOR.inline( 'editable1', {
       toolbar: [ ... ]
   } );
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you is the CKEditor-man! I and testing and will back later.