# Where the list of all toolbar button names and group names available in CKEditor 4?

Tags: validation, ckeditor

This question is similar to [What toolbar buttons are available in CKEditor 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13828383/287948) and a [reinforce of this old other one](http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor/Complete-list-of-toolbar-items). I add here some perceptions and personal difficulties that I faced.

The CKEditor documentation is good, but pulverized and "incomplete" for *Javascript programmers* (first-time CKEditor deployer), because "stops in the middle"...  Examples:

- if I need [removeButtons](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-removeButtons), I need also the **list of valid names**.
- if I need to customize — by source-code, changing array elements —, I need not only clues and examples as [here](http://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/plugins/toolbar/toolbar.html), but a full list of valid names, syntax rules, context exceptions, and perhaps a list of "official plugin names".

**QUESTION: there are a command (a simple `alert(debug)`) or a documented list of all possible names?** (or all controled and registered plugin-names, group-names, etc.)

---

... CKEditor4 is promoted as (the best of the best!) "plug and play" editor, but, for programmers, it is false, without proper "managing controlled-names" support.

NOTE: all `config.js` need a reference to *valid names*, and no documentation show a list of all valid names for my changes at `config.js` arrays.  This is all that a programmer need, but today (August 2013) we need to expend most of time using Google to find valid names, or using browser's "element inspector" to get clues about it. With no name, no programming task is simple at *config array*.

DREAM: for *web designer* the [ckeditor.com/download](http://ckeditor.com/download) supply a good "customize ckeditor" (!!). But for developers, there are no tool or illustration showing "*button icons* and associated *names*", or group names, etc... That is, an "organized map from features to names" (and vice-versa). For each map we need also, of course, the "context exceptions", like ["Source" that not works with inline editor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18431178/287948).

---

---

(**More practical examples**, edit after @Noseratio and @davidkonrad comments). The problem is "what the valid name for each context?"

If I have at my `config` something like,

```
editor.config.toolbarGroups = [
    { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
             ...
    { name: 'styles' },
    { name: 'colors' },
];
```

and I need to change `{ name: 'styles' }` to a customized one, for example I need this functions:

```
  { name: 'styles', items : [ 'Styles', 'Format', 'FontSize' ] }
```

so, I need to know all that names, and when (contexts) to use properties "name", "items", "groups" with these names. I do a bug if I use "items" at toolbarGroups property, or if I use "Fontsize" instead "FontSize". Also, with `addButtonCommand` and others, I need to know any valid parameter. It is WRONG to to define,

```
  addButtonCommand( 'FontSize', lang.underline, 'underline',
                     config.coreStyles_underline );
```

but is difficult to work without knowing "all valid names list" for each context.

---

(**More practical examples**, edit after @MahanGM comment)

If I use [this v4 guide and instructions](http://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/plugins/toolbar/toolbar.html)
(that is [equivalent to this v3](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Toolbar)), I have "name problems", when using CKEditor4 and inline editor:

- The "default CKEditor toolbar setting" is the "full toolbar"?
- If I take off 'spellchecker' (old v3 name 'SpellChecker'), why not work? and why need take off also 'Scayt'?
- What *names* I can use with inline editor?  When use *groups* and when use *items* in the `editor.config.toolbar` array?
- ... etc. ... (read my question: all the problem is the correct choice of *valid name* in a  *context*)... Programmer need a "complete [formal specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_specification)", not only clues and fragments of information.

Comment: A good question. I routinely find myself cross-searching through the CKEditor source code for `addCommand` and `addButtonCommand`.

Comment: You are right, deleted the "answer" (did not pay attention)

Comment: Thanks to try (!). I edited adding "more practical examples".

Comment: @Noseratio, thanks to remember `addButtonCommand` it is other goof "config tool", but it also need that programmer know "the names" (see my new example). My problem is with *names* and context of use ;-)

Comment: @PeterKrauss, that's how I find the names and contexts, across all plugins. Awkward, I know :] I'll keep watching this question for a better way.

Comment: You mean this: http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Toolbar (this is for version 3)

Answer (score 1):

(this is not an answer but a suggestion for it, you can copy/paste to post yours)

(you can also colabore editing here)

### "Item by Item" Configuration##

Your editor will work exactly as in your "toolbox definition": a simple JavaScript array,

```
config.toolbar = [ G1, G2, ..., GN ];
```

controlling "every single toolbar in the toolbox" by its contents and by defining their precise position.
The *toolbar definitions*, G<sub>i</sub>,  can be arrays or strings:

- When G<sub>i</sub>  is a string, it is the *bar-line separator*, `'/'`;
- When G<sub>i</sub> is an array, it is a sequence (alias "group") of *button names* (alias "item").

So, the general form of the [*toolbox definition* array](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-toolbar) is

```
config.toolbar = [
     ['ITEM11', 'ITEM12', ..., 'ITEM1N'], 'BAR_SEP',
     ['ITEM21', 'ITEM22', ..., 'ITEM2N'], ...
];
```

where **ITEM<sub>i,j</sub> is a valid *button name***. In [ABNF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5234) it is,

```
 ITEM      =  BUTNAME / "-"
 BUTNAME   = 1*ALPHA      ; and usually a CamelCase name.
```

Scenarios (that define "namespaces") of configuration at August 2013, with CKEditor v4:

1. `git clone git://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-releases.git`
2. Other that have less plugins or less code.
3. Other that have more (oficially registered namespace) plugins.

Software context where the `BUTNAME`s  are valid:

- the *associeated plugin* (see below the table of "Full list of valid BUTNAMEs") is installed (see scenarios 1, 2 or 3);
- the BUTNAME is not at `config.removeButtons` list, neither the associated plugin removed at `config.removePlugins`;
- ... the BUTNAME is defined for that CKEditor version (ex. use 'spellchecker' for v4 and 'SpellChecker' for v3).

#### All registered plugin names

See `config.plugins` in the *scenario-1*, this is the list of all *valid names* for plugins (alphabetic order):

```
 a11yhelp,about,basicstyles,blockquote,button,clipboard,contextmenu,dialog,
 dialogui,elementspath,enterkey,entities,eqneditor,fakeobjects,filebrowser,
 find,floatingspace,floatpanel,horizontalrule,htmlwriter,image,indent,
 indentlist,link,list,magicline,maximize,menu,menubutton,panel,pastefromword,
 pastetext,popup,removeformat,resize,save,scayt,showblocks,sourcearea,
 specialchar,tab,table,tabletools,toolbar,undo,wsc,wysiwygarea
 ,... ? ... more?
```

They are also "plugin" or are "extraplugin"? See *scenario-3*:

```
 texttransform, etc.
```

PS: with *scenario-1*. at the `plugins/`  directory we have only,

```
a11yhelp   dialog           icons.png  magicline      specialchar  wsc
about      fakeobjects      image      pastefromword  table
clipboard  icons_hidpi.png  link       scayt          tabletools
```

###Full list of valid BUTNAMEs###

Specification of all names and related contexts. The plugins are sufixed by "-1" or "-3" to remember the scenario's "namespace".

```
BUTNAME                  | PLUGIN            |  Invalid context
-------------------------|-------------------|------------------
Bold                     | default-1         | ?Always ok? no excetions?
Italic                   | default-1         | ...
...                      | ...               | ...
Source                   | default-1         | not works with inline editor
...                      | ...               | ...
TransformTextToUppercase | texttransform-3   | scenario-1
TransformTextCapitalize  | texttransform-3   | scenario-1
...                      | ...               | ...
```

*(this answer will be complete if we can complete this table!)*

Comment: It seems there is no way to get a separator (not a newline `/`) between groups - wtf!? Any ideas (apart from putting both groups in one item array)?

Answer (score 1):

This one from [Toolbar Configuration](http://nightly.ckeditor.com/15-06-01-06-08/full/samples/plugins/toolbar/toolbar.html) helped me a lot:

```
// Toolbar configuration generated automatically by the editor based on config.toolbarGroups.
config.toolbar = [
    { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ], items: [ 'Source', '-', 'Save', 'NewPage', 'Preview', 'Print', '-', 'Templates' ] },
    { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ], items: [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo' ] },
    { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ], items: [ 'Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', '-', 'Scayt' ] },
    { name: 'forms', items: [ 'Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton', 'HiddenField' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ], items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ], items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl', 'Language' ] },
    { name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor' ] },
    { name: 'insert', items: [ 'Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak', 'Iframe' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'styles', items: [ 'Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize' ] },
    { name: 'colors', items: [ 'TextColor', 'BGColor' ] },
    { name: 'tools', items: [ 'Maximize', 'ShowBlocks' ] },
    { name: 'others', items: [ '-' ] },
    { name: 'about', items: [ 'About' ] }
];
```

and

```
// Toolbar groups configuration.
config.toolbarGroups = [
    { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
    { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
    { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
    { name: 'forms' },
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ] },
    { name: 'links' },
    { name: 'insert' },
    '/',
    { name: 'styles' },
    { name: 'colors' },
    { name: 'tools' },
    { name: 'others' },
    { name: 'about' }
];
```

when using in own init:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'topicMessageInput', {
        toolbar: [
                { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ], items: [ 'Source', '-', 'Save', 'NewPage', 'Preview', 'Print', '-', 'Templates' ] },
                { na..
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It seems there is no way to get a separator (not a newline `/`) between groups - wtf!? Any ideas (apart from putting both groups in one item array)?