# CKeditor custom plugins order

Tags: javascript, ckeditor4.x

Hi I am using the ckeditor version 4.3.2 with 4 custom plugins, they appear in the insert toolbar and I am calling the plugins in this way:

```
extraPlugins: 'aexpagebreak,aexextraline,aexsinglecolumn,aextwocolumn',
```

they are loaded fine, but the order of the plugins in the bar randomly change every time that page reload, how can I define a fixed order for the plugin icons in the toolbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the toolbar yourself by defining an object that tells ckeditor how to display and group items.

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_toolbar

From ckeditor docs:

```
config.toolbarGroups = [
    { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
    { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
    { name: 'links' },
    { name: 'insert' },
    { name: 'forms' },
    { name: 'tools' },
    { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
    { name: 'others' },
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ] },
    { name: 'styles' },
    { name: 'colors' },
    { name: 'about' }
];
```

More info:

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_toolbarconcepts-section-toolbar-groups-configuration

Looks like there is a toolbar configurator tool on their site but it may only be for v4.5 and up. Not entirely sure:

http://ckeditor.com/tmp/4.5.0-beta/ckeditor/samples/toolbarconfigurator/index.html#basic

Comment: Thanks, I think that there should be a way without write the whole toolbar structure, but well... by the way, [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442383/where-the-list-of-all-toolbar-button-names-and-group-names-available-in-ckeditor) is a complete toolbar config

Comment: @Cesar yea it is annoying. Had to do it myself before which why I was able to answer.